# GitHub Actions nuget.exe is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: powershell, nuget, github-actions, command-prompt

I have a github actions workflow which I want to run "nuget pack" and "nuget push" commands. To do this I am including "nuget.exe" in my github repo, so it can be downloaded and the commands run using the .exe.
In my GitHub Actions workflow below, everything runs except the ".\nuget.exe pack ..." command

```
name: Release New NuGet Package

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      nugetPkgProjectName:
        description: 'Enter your NuGet Package Project Name:'
        required: true
        type: string
      incrementMinorVersion:
          description: 'Set to "true" if you want to increment minor and set patch to zero.'
          required: false
          type: string
      descriptionVar:
          description: 'What changes were made in this version?'
          required: false
          type: string

jobs:
  begin:
    runs-on: martin-laptop
    steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            sparse-checkout: |
              Martin Nuget Work

        - name: Run Nuget Pack Command   
          run: |
           cd "Martin Nuget Work"
           .\nuget.exe pack template.nuspec -Version 3.3.3 -Properties id=MyCoolPackage.fpga
```

if I run the command `.\nuget.exe pack template.nuspec -Version 3.3.3 -Properties id=MyCoolPackage.fpga` in command prompt, it works perfectly fine. but when i run the github actions workflow, i get this error:

```
Run cd "Martin Nuget Work"
Program 'nuget.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At 
C:\actions-runner\_work\_temp\zzzzz.ps1:3 char:1
+ .\nuget.exe pack template.nuspec -Version 0.0.0 -Properties id=Proteg ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At C:\actions-runner\_work\_temp\zzzzzz.ps1:3 char:1
+ .\nuget.exe pack template.nuspec -Version 0.0.0 -Properties id=Proteg ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Why isnt my github actions workflow able to run this exe that I include in my repo?

Comment: There are specific tasks for different tool acquisition, and this one is for NuGet, https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-nuget-exe-for-use-with-actions

Comment: I tried to use that official nuget github actions package, but am getting this error now 'Error: unable to get local issuer certificate'

Comment: You are not the first one to hit similar issues, so check out https://github.com/NuGet/setup-nuget/issues?q=is:issue+is:closed

Comment: Having the nuget exe packaged and portable in my github repo had worked before, and Im hoping it could still work, because setting up an env var to point to some certificate as NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS  for every machine using a github actions runner sounds very difficult.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the .NET cli instead of nuget.exe?

Comment: @BenjaminMichaelis Im trying to make it so running my github actions will do all the setup / install necesary to run nuget push and nuget pack commands. the .net cli would need to be installed by the user outisde of their github actions runner?

Comment: What about with the https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet action in your workflow?

Comment: @BenjaminMichaelis tried using the dotnet workflow, results in this error: `Error: Failed to install dotnet, exit code: 1. dotnet-install: Failed to extract package. Exception: Exception calling "ExtractToFile" with "3" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is denied."` I'm investigating